# cygwin/unix finding text followed after/before some pattern

Tags: unix, sed, cygwin

consider we have text:

```
<li><a href="link">text1</a>
```

What is the fastest way to get "link" (url before text1).

Considering same case, how would it be possible to find text following a link, f.e.
providing "link", would expect getting text1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `sed`:

To find 'link':

```
echo '<li><a href="link">text1</a>' | sed 's/.*"\([^"]\+\)">text1.*/\1/'
```

To find 'text1':

```
echo '<li><a href="link">text1</a>' | sed 's/.*"link">\([^<]\+\).*/\1/'
```

---

Using `grep` and `Perl` regexp:

To find 'link':

```
echo '<li><a href="link">text1</a>' | grep -oP '[^"]*(?=">text1)'
```

To find 'text1':

```
echo '<li><a href="link">text1</a>' | grep -oP '(?<="link">)[^<]*'
```

Comment: what if i would have space in between </a> link?

Comment: @SauliusS: I'm not sure where you're indicating the space to be. Do you mean like this: `<li><a href="link"> </a>`? Please use backticks to format your code. Cheers.

Comment: as in example consider 

<li><a href="link">text1</a>

Comment: failed to edit last comment (edit goes here)

        <a...>text1</a>
        <a...> text1</a>
        <a...>text1 </a>

What is the best way to do "like" type operations?

backticks: can't make them work

Comment: @SauliusS: Sorry I don't think I understand what you're trying to accomplish. I'd recommend editing your question with the sample data above as well as listing some expected output.

Comment: @SauliusS: Just a guess... To find the word 'link', try: `echo '<a href="link"> text1 </a>' | sed 's/.*"\([^"]\+\)"> *text1.*/\1/'`. Also, this is a backtick: `\``. HTH.

Comment: i was interested how to make sed operation similar to sql `%` , what means 0/more elements

Comment: @SauliusS: Place the `*` after any character to get the effect of zero or more times. For example, ` *` would mean match a space zero or more times. `.*` means match any character zero or more times. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

**get link**

try grep

```
grep -Po '(?<=href=")[^"]*' file
```

test with your example:

```
kent$  echo '<li><a href="link">text1</a>'|grep -Po '(?<=href=")[^"]*'
link
```

**get text**

assume you save "link" in a variable `l`:

```
grep -Po "(?<=href=\"$l\">)[^<]*"
```

will give you text

try with your example:

```
kent$  l=link                                                               

kent$  echo '<li><a href="link">text1</a>'|grep -Po "(?<=href=\"$l\">)[^<]*"
text1
```

Comment: well, the problem is in the file i have more href's, so i can just use href for link location